# How to delete all rows from all tables where id equals some value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to remove all records from all tables where some 'user_id' = 'some value'. How can I do it in MS SQL 2005?
P.S Cascades is not everywhere.

Comment: Why don't you use foreign-keys? You don't need to set cascade delete, but you should avoid inconsistencies by throwing an error then.

Comment: What is the datatype of user_id? If it is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER this may not be entirely difficult to do... What is your purpose? Is it a single cleaning up operation or do you want to create a function that will remove the users' dependent objects any time a user is deleted?

Comment: Hello @mortb, my purpose is to write script that will remove the user and also users' dependent objects in the entire database (all tables).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one off task then a quick and dirty way. To delete `user_id=999`.

Run

```
SELECT 
        'DELETE FROM ' + quotename(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' 
             + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) + ' WHERE user_id=999'
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1  AND name = 'user_id'
```

Copy and paste the result into SSMS. Execute repeatedly until it gives you no FK errors.

If you need this for more than a one off task you'll need to parameterise the `DELETE` statements and order them in the correct order to avoid FK errors.